# How to figure out the "next page" in sub category and access page by page

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, screen-scraping

i having a problem in accessing the next page in sub category and i need to soup the information page by page.
But in my code i able to soup only the first page of the each sub category.
Can anyone help me how to access the next page in subcategories. Thank you  in advanced.

```
import re           
import urllib
import urllib2
import time  
import sys
from datetime import datetime, date
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
#list
categories=[]
details=[]
tools=[]
pages_details=[]
division =[]
links=[]
link =[]
subcategory=[]
info=[]
Data ={}

url = 'http://www.share-hit.de/'  # website
pageHTML = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHTML)

#find the main category and append to a list
for category in soup.find('td',{'class':'linkmenu'}).findAll('a'):
    categories.append('http://www.share-hit.de/' + category['href']) # print all the categories
print categories
try:
    for i in categories:
        if len(subcategory) != " ":
                del subcategory[:]

        try:    
            pageHTML = urllib2.urlopen(i).read()
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(pageHTML)
            table = soup2.find('table', attrs={'id':'kategoriemenu'})
            division = table.findAll('div',attrs={'align':'left'})
            # find the  sub category of each main category
            for sub_cate in division:
                try:    

                    subcategory.append('http://www.share-hit.de/' + sub_cate.find("a")["href"])
                    print subcategory

                    # Inside each sub category get the application link of first page only 
                    # I need to know the way how to find the next page in each sub category 

                    for apps in subcategory:

                        pageHTML = urllib2.urlopen(apps).read()
                        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(pageHTML)
                        tools = soup2.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'Stil2'})


                    if len(links) != " ":
                            del links[:]
                    # append list of application on each page 
                    for list in tools:
                        try:
                            links.append('http://www.share-hit.de/' + list.find("a")["href"])

                            print links 
                        except Exception:   
                            print 'No Apps'

                    #Details From the application link i manage to soup the details of each application

                except Exception:   
                    print 'No Sub Categories'

        except Exception:
            print 'No Categories'

except Exception:
    print 'Finish'
```

Comment: Do you see any errors? Where is your program failing?

Comment: There is no error. 
  
---for apps in subcategory:
------Next_Page = soup2.findAll('p', attrs={'class':'Stil4'} 

this code can retrieve the next page details .TQ

Comment: hi  shaktimaan any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose a visual scraper like IRobotSoft scraper to handle such problems.  It includes many options you can easily use to navigate through next pages.  The query for you next link is:

```
<a (tx like 'Vorw%')>
```